# Zeroes of entire function on $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Let $n\ge 2$ be an integer and let $f$ be an entire function on $\mathbb C^n$. Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with positive $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Then if $f$ vanishes at $A$, this implies that $f=0$.

Question. Is there an elementary proof of the above statement?

Comment: something like fixing a variable and considering the Taylor coefficients as analytic functions in the other $n-1$ variables and the projection of $A$ on the fixed variable has corresponding (real projection) non zero Lebesgue measure by Fubini, so all those coefficients must be identically zero etc

Comment: If $f$ is nonconstant, $f^{-1}(0)$ is a complex-analytic subvariety of dimension $n-1$. It's intersection with $R^n$ is a real-analytic subvariety of (real) dimension $\le n-1$...

Answer (score 5):

This follows immediatelly from the following paper:

[The Zero Set of a Real Analytic Function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07276)

Comment: Thx, it looks great.

Comment: @Bazin I needed this exact result for a project few years ago, recalled it:) You are welcome